# How to prevent spring security from redirecting to the previous page after successful login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We use Spring Security 2.0.7 :=( in our application.

Spring Security implements the following feature: when an unauthenticated user access page X, the following happens:

- User is redirected to login page
- Upon successful login, the user is redirected to page X instead of the target of the login form.

In my application, for reasons beyond my control, this is not the desired behavior. We want to land on the target page of the login form no matter what the page that the user tried to access.

**Q: Is it possible to disable this feature of Spring Security and how ?**

I suppose one of the filters of the standard filter chain is doing this, but I could not identify which.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try modifying `always-use-default-target="true"` in the  of your Spring Security Configuration xml file.

The default value is `false`, and leads to the behavior you describe.

**Example:**

```
<form-login 
    login-page="/login.html"
    authentication-failure-url="/login.html?status=LOGIN_FAILURE"
    default-target-url="/index.html"
    always-use-default-target="true" />
```

Comment: Would you guys please take a look at this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849246/2556354

Answer (score 1):

For annotation based settings use the following:
.defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",**true**)

The second boolean parameter is setting always-use-default-target value.

Comment: Using spring boot, this is the answer.